# Populate data from an array into an html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>      
  <!-- begin template -->
  <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Relevant Tag Info</th>
          <th>Rating</th>
          <th>Track</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
          <td>James Bond</td>
          <td>Relevant Tag Info</td>
          <td>4 Stars</td>
          <td class="center">Track</td>
          <td class="center">Edit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
          <td>James Bond</td>
          <td>Relevant Tag Info</td>
          <td>4 Stars</td>
          <td class="center">Track</td>
          <td class="center">Edit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
          <td>James Bond</td>
          <td>Relevant Tag Info</td>
          <td>4 Stars</td>
          <td class="center">Track</td>
          <td class="center">Edit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
          <td>James Bond</td>
          <td>Relevant Tag Info</td>
          <td>4 Stars</td>
          <td class="center">Track</td>
          <td class="center">Edit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
          <td>James Bond</td>
          <td>Relevant Tag Info</td>
          <td>4 Stars</td>
          <td class="center">Track</td>
          <td class="center">Edit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
          <td>James Bond</td>
          <td>Relevant Tag Info</td>
          <td>4 Stars</td>
          <td class="center">Track</td>
          <td class="center">Edit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
          <td>James Bond</td>
          <td>Relevant Tag Info</td>
          <td>4 Stars</td>
          <td class="center">Track</td>
          <td class="center">Edit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
          <td>James Bond</td>
          <td>Relevant Tag Info</td>
          <td>4 Stars</td>
          <td class="center">Track</td>
          <td class="center">Edit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
          <td>James Bond</td>
          <td>Relevant Tag Info</td>
          <td>4 Stars</td>
          <td class="center">Track</td>
          <td class="center">Edit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
          <td>James Bond</td>
          <td>Relevant Tag Info</td>
          <td>4 Stars</td>
          <td class="center">Track</td>
          <td class="center">Edit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
          <td>James Bond</td>
          <td>Relevant Tag Info</td>
          <td>4 Stars</td>
          <td class="center">Track</td>
          <td class="center">Edit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
          <td>James Bond</td>
          <td>Relevant Tag Info</td>
          <td>4 Stars</td>
          <td class="center">Track</td>
          <td class="center">Edit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
          <td>James Bond</td>
          <td>Relevant Tag Info</td>
          <td>4 Stars</td>
          <td class="center">Track</td>
          <td class="center">Edit</td>
        </tr>    
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
          <td>James Bond</td>
          <td>Relevant Tag Info</td>
          <td>4 Stars</td>
          <td class="center">Track</td>
          <td class="center">Edit</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

I am trying to grab data from

```
var dResponse = [{"user_id":"1","user_firstname":"Mark","user_lastname":"Woo","user_latitude":"37.7902","user_longitude":"-122.458"}, {"user_id":"2","user_firstname":"Hualong","user_lastname":"Chen","user_latitude":"37.7285","user_longitude":"-122.438"},{"user_id":"3","user_firstname":"TFirst","user_lastname":"TLast","user_latitude":"37.7401","user_longitude":"-122.492"},{"user_id":"4","user_firstname":"Zishan","user_lastname":"Budhwani","user_latitude":"37.7298","user_longitude":"-122.47"},{"user_id":"5","user_firstname":"ibian","user_lastname":"hodgson","user_latitude":"37.8014","user_longitude":"-122.427"},{"user_id":"6","user_firstname":"Amos","user_lastname":"Munoz","user_latitude":"37.7367","user_longitude":"-122.439"},{"user_id":"7","user_firstname":"Brennan","user_lastname":"Ramos","user_latitude":"37.7624","user_longitude":"-122.435"},{"user_id":"8","user_firstname":"Cole","user_lastname":"Lott","user_latitude":"37.7607","user_longitude":"-122.462"},{"user_id":"9","user_firstname":"Slade","user_lastname":"Strickland","user_latitude":"37.796","user_longitude":"-122.451"},{"user_id":"10","user_firstname":"Isaiah","user_lastname":"Gibbs","user_latitude":"37.7536","user_longitude":"-122.464"}];
```

and assign each piece of data into its correct category.

Example:    User_id:1 should create the first user with firstname,last name, lat, and long.

Will look like:

First Name:     Last Name:       Latitude:          Longitude:

Mark              Woo              37.7902             -122.458

Comment: what have you tried so far? Displaying some source code and attempts would be a great help for us to help you. We debug your code and explains the reasons for it not working and give you any solutions if we have any.

Comment: This is what I have so far. Lost on where to begin to populate each piece of table data with that of what's in the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this works, i hope this is what you're looking for.

The main point of this answer is for you to take note of the `for loop` to understand how you access the object data. I'm sure you can improve on the way you handle the data after that.

```js
function Table(){
var dResponse = [
    {"user_id":"1","user_firstname":"Mark","user_lastname":"Woo","user_latitude":"37.7902","user_longitude":"-122.458"},
    {"user_id":"2","user_firstname":"Hualong","user_lastname":"Chen","user_latitude":"37.7285","user_longitude":"-122.438"},
    {"user_id":"3","user_firstname":"TFirst","user_lastname":"TLast","user_latitude":"37.7401","user_longitude":"-122.492"},
    {"user_id":"4","user_firstname":"Zishan","user_lastname":"Budhwani","user_latitude":"37.7298","user_longitude":"-122.47"},
    {"user_id":"5","user_firstname":"ibian","user_lastname":"hodgson","user_latitude":"37.8014","user_longitude":"-122.427"},
    {"user_id":"6","user_firstname":"Amos","user_lastname":"Munoz","user_latitude":"37.7367","user_longitude":"-122.439"},
    {"user_id":"7","user_firstname":"Brennan","user_lastname":"Ramos","user_latitude":"37.7624","user_longitude":"-122.435"},
    {"user_id":"8","user_firstname":"Cole","user_lastname":"Lott","user_latitude":"37.7607","user_longitude":"-122.462"},
    {"user_id":"9","user_firstname":"Slade","user_lastname":"Strickland","user_latitude":"37.796","user_longitude":"-122.451"},
    {"user_id":"10","user_firstname":"Isaiah","user_lastname":"Gibbs","user_latitude":"37.7536","user_longitude":"-122.464"}
];
 // Target the Table you want to insert the Data to
var results=document.getElementById('Results');
results.innerHTML += "<tr><td>User ID</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>latitude</td><td>longitude</td></tr>";
   for(var obj in dResponse){
      //Loop through the object to get each objects data
results.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+dResponse[obj].user_id+"</td><td>"+dResponse[obj].user_firstname+"</td><td>"+dResponse[obj].user_lastname+"</td><td>"+dResponse[obj].user_latitude+"</td><td>"+dResponse[obj].user_longitude+"</td></tr>";
   }

}
window.onload=Table;
```

```html
<table id="Results">
</table>
```

I hope this help you. Happy coding!

Comment: Working through it now but it looks exactly how I want it, thank you!

Comment: No problem, if you have any questions feel free to ask and I will add more comments if needed.

Comment: Would you recommend DLing the jquery table sorter plugin to make this sortable or is there a better way?

Comment: I haven't dealt with or needed to use sort-able tables but i'm sure you can find many plug-ins but unfortunately I don't have any references for you on that one sorry.

Comment: What about adding an edit feature at the end of each user line?

Comment: Editing isn't in this question but it's very possible. If you don't know how then i can only recommend you do some research and attempt this on your own. If you find a method you want to go with but have trouble getting it to work then come back and check for related questions, if you cannot find previous answers that help you  submit a new question  with the relevant source code. I'm sure someone will help you, who knows it could be me! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/khynzpbz/) with jQuery.

Looping through the object and accessing their properties with dot notation.

Eg: `object.user_firstname`

Comment: What would the loop look like?

Comment: I'm using jQuery $.each function. You can loop using Javascript for loop like @NewToJS example.

Comment: Dan Basinski, some people like to use Javascript and some like to use jQuery. Having multiple options is never a bad thing so if you want to learn from this i would take note of both answers. @Syahrul Great answer! I will vote up on this.